# failed to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22 and com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.1.2

Tags: android, rendering, android-appcompat

I installed `ALL Extra` and `SDK API 21-22` including changed

`compileSdkVersion 22 to 21` and `buildToolsVersion '22.0.1' to 21.1.2`.

I'm having Rendering Problems for `API 22`.
I have tried changing the version to <= 21 but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: Choose from here as per your `compileSdkVersion`: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html

Answer (score 126, accepted):

These are the correct version that you can add in your build.gradle according to the API needs.

**API 24:**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
```

**API 25:**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
```

**API 26:**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

**API 27:**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Is there a Android resource where one can see the different versions?

Comment: @powder366 you can check the versions in `SDK Manager`.

Comment: @powder366 see my answeir below, how to determine version of support lib availiable

Comment: appcompat-v7 **23.3.0** is available.

Comment: Before going into this make sure Android Support Reporistory is installed as suggested in other answers.

Comment: What about com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1' ??

Comment: The answer is no longer up to date

Comment: Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward.

Answer (score 25):

In order to make that working I had to set:

```
compile ("com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0")
compile ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0")
compile ("com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0")
compile ("com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0")
compile ("com.android.support:design:22.2.0")
```

compile ("com.android.support:**design**:22.**2**.0")

Documentation states something different ([docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design)):

com.android.support:**support**-design:22.**0**.0

Answer (score 24):

Real path for Support Repository Libraries:

[image]

1. You should download Support Repository Libraries.

If the problem still exists:

2. Go to the real path of your Support Repository Libraries and check that the following folder exists:

   ```
   "ANDROID_SDK_DIRECTORY\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support"
   ```

   In that folder there are support libraries that can't be found.
   for example:

   ```
   "ANDROID_SDK_DIRECTORY\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7"
   ```
3. Open folder `appcompat-v7` and you see folders with all available version. You should use only one of these versions in the build.gradle file  dependencies or use +, for ex. 18.0.+

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
       compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
   }
   ```

That is the path taken from grade.build dependencies file:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0
```

Refer to the real path on your HDD -->

```
ANDROID_SDK_DIRECTORY\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\18.0.0
```

If there is no such folder, you will receive the error:

```
"failed to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0"
```

**p.s.**  If you have Windows x64, when installing sdk and jdk, make sure that the installation path does not have `Program Files(86)`. Brackets that add Windows may cause additional problems with resolving paths for your project. Use simple paths for your installation folder.

For example:

```
c:\androidSDK\
```

Comment: I do not have any such folder and hence get the error you mentioned: "failed to resolve...". From here onwards, how can I solve this issue?Any idea?

Answer (score 17):

> Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0

The "I literally tried everything else" answer:

This problem will also occur if you don't have an upto date Android Support Library and Android Support Repository. Just install using the SDK manager.

Comment: Not that the other answers are incorrect, but the problem for me was our build machine didn't have the updated Support Library.

Comment: Of course not. But when you google this error and you try every variation of compile and nothing works, this is the usually the culprit and its not entirely obvious to figure out on your own. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 9):

Along with other provided solutions, make sure to have the following within project/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in support libraries you always need to add three numbers as version number

Suppose for 22 -> you need to write it as 22.0.0, not just 22

for 22.1 -> 22.1.0

So your dependencies should look like this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
```

I Programmers language you need to pad extra zeros.

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: "and you got error when you used "21.1.2" because you already updated the support library to 22.0.0. so 21.1.2 does not exist anymore."

That is so untrue. When you update libraries that doesn't mean you can't use the older versions

Answer (score 2):

i solve it

change 22.0.0 to 21.0.3

```
dependencies {

 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'  }
```

maybe i have download the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3` but have not got the   `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'`

when i use SDK Manager update my `support library` and `support repository` , the problem dismissed.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE1**: All `com.android.support` libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes).

**NOTE2**: Support library should not use a different version than the compileSdkVersion

For **API 28** you can use:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0-alpha1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/recyclerview-v7/28.0.0-alpha1

All support libraries: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use "**+**" sign in the version number. For example

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.+'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+"
```

In this case you won't have to change versions for the same API number

Comment: never use + sign, it will lead to unpredictable behavior, unless you are absolutely sure

Comment: I've seen using "+" in build.gradle file in several topics of Android Developers documentation. For example, [link1](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html) or [link2](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) and others (you need to scroll the page to see it). 
There was no mentioning about any problems with this and I also have never had any.
But if you did it would be helpful to add some links with description of the problem.

Comment: if you use + your build has dynamic behavior, you wont be sure which version will be resolved. External changes  may cause bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Messages Gradle Sync, and Click on Install Repository and sync project. This is will install needed file in Android SDK and after syncing you will be able to create gradle or run your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicated answer. Please see Ashraf Alshahawy's answer above

Comment: @MoZaatar  It's not a duplicate answer I want to show that if you have put google() line below then also this error happened so put top of the all line like my answer.
I am not copy anyone answer.

Comment: @MoZaatar If those answer has google() line then i choose edit or comment.Why should i give as a new answer.I solved this issue this way so i put my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you import them? Like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
compile ("com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0")
compile ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0")
compile ("com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0")
compile ("com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0")
compile ("com.android.support:design:22.2.0")
```

paste the above code in your app gradle.

and while setting up the project select empty activity instead of blank activity.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue by changing these

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
```

that means your target SDK version should be same as version of cardView and recyclerView and other google libraries.

```
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Answer (score 0):

I had such dependancy in build.gradle -

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

But it causes unstable builds. Ensure it works ok for you, and look in your android sdk manager for current version of support lib available, and replace this dependency with

```
def final RECYCLER_VIEW_VER = '23.1.1'
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${RECYCLER_VIEW_VER}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tools > Android > SDK Manager

Select all of the packages that are not up to date and update them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem updating all packages from Android SDK Manager and also, I had to install `Extras -> Android Support Repository`.