# Failed to resolve only recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

i have a strange error
this is my error Capture
[image: show me error]

[Big Size Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysTbe.png)

I had to install Support Repository and Support Libray
but recyclerview is not found

If I click on "Install repository and sync project" ,

show this window
[image]

and finish,project clean,
but still same error

Search of hard work, but it does not solve
thanks

i already seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284236/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v722-and-com-android-supportre) Question
Try 21.0.1,2,3,+
still same error
[image]

Comment: in the build.gradle change to 22.2.0 instead of 21.1. you have installed 22.2

Comment: @MohammedImranN 22.2.0, 21.1.0 same not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your dependency, a dot instead of the colon after the group ID.

It should say:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
                            ^
```

Also, consider using the latest versions (22.2.0) instead of 21.0.0.

Comment: I made a typo in my answer as well :) Fixed it now (compile instead of import).