# failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-support-library, floating-action-button

I'm using Android Studio. I use floating action button so when i use it gives me error and tell me to update android support library v7 to 22.2.0 version. 
so when i update v7 support library to 22.2.0 version and make synchronization then it gives me error failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 version.
 How to resolved this error?

Comment: First of all, update your SDK Manager, then update your gradle files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just update your `support library and support repository & your SDK Manager` , 
Then

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Please check this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284236/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v722-and-com-android-supportre)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Android Studio**, make sure you downloaded the support repository using **SDK Manager**

Answer (score 0):

Update your **`gradle`** file with this section:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
}
```