# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've always programmed Android with Eclipse and decided to start migrating to [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio). I decided to use the same SDK I already had for Eclipse, then:

- Started a new project
- Set minimum SDK 4.0 (API Level 14)
- Choose Blank Activity option
- Used Default names for Activity Name and Layout Name
- Hit Finish

After a few seconds Gradle finishes the build, and it throws me two errors with the following messages in file Teste4\app\build\intermediates/exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml:

> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. 
>     
>   Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Under *File -> Project Structure -> Modules: app (left column) -> Properties tab*, I have the following versions set up:

- "Compile Sdk Version": Android 5.1 (API Level 22)
- "Build Tools Version": 23.0.2

What should I do in order to fix this?

I already tried what was suggested in Stack Overflow question *[appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676)*, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1156, accepted):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.

Since you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.

Alternatively you can continue compiling against version 22 of the Android SDK by switching to the latest support library v22.

Comment: How can I change the version for the support library to 22?

Comment: You can either change it manually in your `build.gradle`, or you can use the GUI by opening up the project properties and going to the "dependencies" tab.

Comment: Ended up installing v23 of the SDK and that solved the problem. Tried to lower the version to 22, but it wasn't available on the GUI or give me an error on changing build.gradle (I'm a complete newbie about gradle, so please forgive me). Thanks! Did you managed to lower the version "4k3R"?

Comment: I'm confused... I was under the impression that Android apps were forward-compatible, right? So if I target the 4.0 API, and try running it on a 5.1 virtual device (whatever those API levels are), why wouldn't it work? If I raise the API level so that the app works on my 5.1 virtual device, won't the app be incompatible with 5.0 and below?

Comment: This question and answer have nothing to do with what version your app will run on. An app targeting 22 can run just fine on a device running 23. The problem described here is that the support library version 23 requires that you target 23, as the support library references some APIs in the 23 SDK.

Comment: This answer did not help me. I use the v7 support library. In the `project.properties` under `android_sdk_path\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`, I see `target=android-19`. Setting `compileSdkVersion = 19` in `build.gradle (app)` didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Oh, okay, I just figured out there's a difference between the api level you target ant the minimum api level.

Comment: For those like me who are new to Android Studio and are confused about how to "use the GUI by opening up the project properties", in my Android Studio (v1.3.1), I go to File, Project Structure, then in the left-hand pane at the bottom is an entry under Modules (called "app" in my case).  I click on that, and then I see a Dependencies tab.

Comment: I still can't believe Android Studio releases stuff without even testing something SO basic!! At least put some meaningful warnings!!

Comment: @Josh this is not an Android Studio problem, it's the story library. They could definitely use some documentation surrounding it though.

Comment: The GUI should have popped up a message "we've detected you're not targeting the right Android API version. Want me to fix it?". Instead, I have to stop working on the airplane and wait until I can search stackoverflow.

Comment: Helped in my scenario, I added 
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
and then I used 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' in "dependencies". and it worked fine.

Comment: That is funny. If you complile with API23 that also produces errors. And stackoverflow for those error say you should compile with API21. Circle completed.

Comment: I have `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"` `compileSdkVersion 21` and dependency `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1'` I found that I had to clean the project, after changing appcompat version, in order to overcome the error `cannot resolve symbol R`

Comment: Is there a straight forward way to switch to v22 of support library in Eclipse?

Comment: @Tanis.7x Even After doing these changes error not solved. Still I have these errors in `v23/values-23.xml` file. I've `compileSdkVersion:22,buildToolsVersion "22.0.1", targetSdkVersion 22,` and dependence `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'` then rebuild app. But still facing the issue :(

Comment: @Prabs You are probably referencing a resource (such as a style) that was introduced in API 23 in that file. This will not work if you compile against API 22.

Comment: @Tanis.7x That style is auto generated. I'm not using it anyway. And it is not allowing me to delete it. How do I overcome this situation.

Comment: @Tanis.7x Problem solved. I've updated to API 23 and to use apache I've followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32108524/4361127) it's working now :)

Comment: Android Studio 2.0, I had to add both the following dependencies in build.gradle (but done through the project structure -- modules -- dependences tab: appcompat-v7:23.3.0 and support:design:23.3.0. Compiling at version 23, buildtools at 23.0.3 with a minsdk version >= 10.

Comment: I am trying to add "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0" from the "Dependencies" tab, but I do not see it available for me. I see "com.android.support:appcompat-v7 (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1)". Do they only show the latest versions?

Comment: I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284236/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v722-and-com-android-supportre as a reference. In my file C:\Users\jaimemontoya\Downloads\CouponClub2\app\build.gradle, specifically in the dependencies {} section, I am adding the corresponding dependencies according to the "compileSdkVersion" and "buildToolsVersion" that I want to use.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya the list will only populate with the latest version for each library, but you can always specify the version yourself in the dialog before you hit "ok"

Comment: When I try to enter something invalid, I get this message: "Please enter a valid coordinate, discover it or select one from the list". But if I need an older version of a dependency, I can just type in a valid one, as you mentioned Tanis.7x.

Comment: in my case i was using `compile sdk 23` and `build tools 25.0.0` just changed `compile sdk` to 25 and done..

Answer (score 142):

This happens because after updates Android Studio uses **API version 23** by default.

The following worked for me:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to get to the project structure page.  Go to the properties tab and change **23.0.0** to **22.0.1** (or equivalent to what you were using earlier) in the build tool area and rebuild your project.

If that doesn't work, go to **gradle:app** and then

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

Edit **v7:23.0.0** to **v7:22.2.1** as shown above and sync gradle. This will definitely work.

Comment: For newbies like me who are confused about how to "go to gradele:app and then compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'", in my Android Studio (version 1.3.1), in the project pane (which I opened by clicking the 1: Project tab on the very left), I see two entries under Gradle Scripts called "build.gradle".  The second one has (Module: app) next to it.  I double-clicked it to open it.  Then in the dependencies section at the bottom, I changed the v7:23.0.0 to v7:22.2.1.  I saved (and synced as prompted by Studio) - seemed to compile ok.

Comment: How can I enter project structure page on MAC?

Comment: @Sourav Even After doing these changes error not solved. Still I have these errors in `v23/values-23.xml` file. I've changed values in project structure page, rebuild app. But still facing the issue :(

Comment: On mac the shortcut is ⌘ +  ;  . Alternatively you can go to File > Project Structure.

Answer (score 117):

**When you update your Android Studio, it uses API version 23 by default,
which is the main reason for its occurrence. So,**

At first, check your AppCompat version in build.gradle(Module:app)
That is,

[image]

If after changing to 23 there occurs an error then just download

`Compile Sdk Version to API 23, and Build Tools Version to 23.0.0`

from SDK Manager. If already downloaded then:

```
1. Go to SDK Manager and
2. Under Project Structure, change *Compile SDK Version* to API 23, and *Build Tools Version* to 23.0.0
```

Click the SDK Manager Button and open the dialog.

[image]

Click SDK Platform and check if Android 6.0 is downloaded or not.

if not, then download that first. After completing the download, click <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

[image]

Now you need to apply changes to your project from setting.
Then press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>** to open setting

1. Click the app from the list.
2. Click properties
3. Change your *Compile SDK Version* to API 23
4. Change your *Build Tools Version* to 23.0.0

[image]

Don't forget to rebuild your project.

Then your error will be gone.

Comment: I understood your way of defining the solution, but try to describe your post with complete description

Comment: @NaveedAhmad Ok i am going to edit my post.
 Thanks for your suggestion .

Comment: I added a post related to the above issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/32370099/2915785

Comment: hey, please add same appcompat version, it solved my problem

Comment: ya that will do both are related so

Comment: In such cases screenshots help for such dummies as I am.

Answer (score 69):

If you've tried to change target to a previous GooglePlayServices or AppCompatv7 version and it doesn't work, check if you have any project-libraries dependency, this project will be targeting the latest version of any of these libraries. It happened to me with the Google Maps Utils Library project:

replace:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

Then you can continue full targeting API 22

If it still doesn't compile, sometimes is useful to set compileSdkVersion API to 23 and targetSdkVersion to 22.

Answer (score 36):

I agree with the previous answer. Your compile SDK version must match the support library. Here is what I did.

1. You can go to SDK Manager and under SDK Platform, install the Android 5.X with API level 23.
2. Under Project Structure, change compile SDK Version to API 23, and Build Tools Version to 23.0.0

Then it should build without problem.

Answer (score 23):

You need to set compileSdkVersion to 23.

Since API 23 Android removed the deprecated Apache Http packages, so if you use them for server requests, you'll need to add useLibrary `'org.apache.http.legacy'` to `build.gradle` as stated in this link:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    ...

    //only if you use Apache packages
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 16):

**This issue is raised because now the compile SDK version must match the Android Support library's major version.**

In my case i have the `Android Support Library` version 23, so i had to compile against the `Android SDK version 23`, and I had to change this in my `build.gradle` file:

[image]

Well some of you will need to install the SDK, `Android 6.0 (API 23)`

[image]

and don´t forget to **Sync project with gradle files**

Answer (score 13):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution, Problem started when I updated sdk, after that I used different **buildToolsVersion ('22.0.1')**  and I was using different **support** library like **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'**, showing you in image below

[image]

This was raising problem of "**android.widget.Material**..."
Then I used same version for support library like  **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'** and its DONE. (Showing you in below screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You should compile your project with latest version so update & install from your SDK. Sync your project with `sync project with Gradle file` Button.
You can also continue with the existing version but check it installed properly below image indicate to API 22 that is properly installed. [image]

And sync your project if needed.

[image]

it may help.

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out by Tanis.7x, the support library version (23) does not match the targetSdkVersion (22)

You can fix this by doing the following:

In the `build.grade` file of your app module, change the following line of code

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

To

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
```

This will use the latest version of the appcompat version that is compatible with SdkVersion 22.

Answer (score 7):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library major version. This is the solution to your problem. You can check it easily in your Gradle Scripts in `build.gradle` file.
Fx: if your `compileSdkVersion` is 23 your compile library must start at 23.

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 340
        versionName "3.4.0"
    }
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

And always check that your Android Studoi has the supported API Level. You can check it in your Android SDK, like this:
 [image]

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was an higher version of Google-play-services. I set them to 7.0.0 (not 8.x) and all was ok.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to downgrade from API 23 to 22 and got this error. I had to change *all* `build.gradle` files in a project in order to compile.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
...
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what helped me: [Adding specific android platform](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/build-failed-android/38071/7)

What should be done is the following... In my case it was `cordova` but the same is relevant for `ionic`, `phonegap` and other frameworks like these:

1. list all platforms installed for your project: `cordova platform list`. You'll see something like this:

[image]

2. remove the android platform: `cordova platform remove android`.
3. then add the specific android platform: `cordova platform add android@5.0.0`.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problems. I solved my problem by updating gradle.build for each sub-module to latest compiler version.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution :
navigate to

```
\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\23.x.x
```

open `.aar` file with 7-zip or winrar , in res folder remove `values-23` folder and save changes .

Answer (score 2):

on module: app (Gradle)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.namepack.nameappxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

project: nameAppXXXX (Gradle)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and edit your activity of AppCompatActivity to for example Activity:

```
package com.namepack.nameappxxxxx;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class NameClass extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything is great but none of you explained where to download the SDK build tools

[image: Everything is greate but none of you explained where to download the SDK build tools]

Answer (score 1):

[image: SDK Manager]

Make sure that all these are in upto date.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade Android Studio.

I had this issue with Android Studio 1.3.1 and none of the other answers worked for me, but after updating to 1.5.1 there were no problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using phonegap(cross-platform) and got same issue above,
just remove the android platform using below command.

**phonegap platform remove android**

And add it again.

**phonegap platform add android**

Then problem solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting errors even after downloading the newest SDK and Android Studio, here is what I did:

1. Download the most recent SDK
2. Open file-Project structure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
3. In modules, select app
4. In the properties tab: Change compile SDK version to API 23 Android 6.0 marshmallow (latest)

I hope it helps someone so that he won't suffer like I did for these couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned your `compile sdk version` must match your `support library's` major version. This is however, also relevant for `subprojects` should you have any.

In case you do, you can set your `subprojects` compile sdk versions with the following script:

```
subprojects { subproject ->
afterEvaluate{
    if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
            buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Add this script in your root `build.gradle` file.