# Android Studio Not Working while building App using AppCompat v23 and API21

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am using Android 1.3 version  and **SDK for 5.0.1** I decrepeted it because whenever I build project it throws error.

Can anyone please tell in details how to do it..

**Error:**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
C:\Users\This-PC\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\This-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.701 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

and

Event Log Shows:

```
10:52:47 PM Platform and Plugin Updates: A new version of Android Studio is available! (show balloon)
10:52:48 PM Gradle sync started
10:53:22 PM Gradle sync failed: failed to find target android-22 : C:\Users\This-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
11:06:43 PM Gradle sync started
11:06:49 PM Gradle sync completed
11:06:50 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
11:07:03 PM Gradle build finished with 3 error(s) in 13s 912ms
11:09:47 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
11:09:50 PM Gradle build finished with 3 error(s) in 2s 345ms
11:10:44 PM Throwable: Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Unknown Host dl.google.com
11:15:08 PM Error Report: Submitted
11:15:55 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
11:15:57 PM Gradle build finished with 3 error(s) in 1s 992ms
```

Comment: `10:52:47 PM Platform and Plugin Updates: A new version of Android Studio is available!` Have you tried updating? V1.3.1 is available.

Comment: Yes I upgrade it both android studio and SDK to API level 23,then also same happen again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio/Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/android-studio-gradle-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the appcompat (and other support libraries) **v23** .
You have to compile your project with **API 23**.

Change in your `build.gradle` the `compileSdkVersion` to **23**

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your SDK to the API 23 (in case you are compiling with 23).
`compileSdkVersion`**,**  and Support Libraries version should be same. The below code indicate that these are same as at line 3 and 2nd line in `dependencies`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.inzi.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Please don't copy and paste your answer in more posts. In this case how do you know the last line of the build.gradle if it is not reported in the original question?
As you can read the gradle stacktrace, the author is using the appcompat23.

And yes, the support libraries v23 have to match the api23 , so you have to compile with api 23.

Comment: yes I got that when gabriele told me I change it.Guess what it running well