# Android - changing compileSdkVersion to 16 leads to compilation errors (gradle)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Just created a new Android app in Studio and I set compileSdkVersion and minSdkVersion to 16, because I want to make sure that I don't use any features in later versions of Android by accident.

However, this line in my build.gradle seems to lead to compilation errors after changing these:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

When I comment it out, compilation will be successful. Do I not need this line? I thought it was necessary for ActionBar, etc.

Do I have the wrong idea to be changing the compileSdkVersion to 16 in the first place to make sure that I don't use new features?

Comment: I get tons of errors like these: Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'. Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.

Comment: You have to use API23 to compile. You can't use API16. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102553/android-studio-not-working-while-building-app-using-appcompat-v23-and-api21/32103832#32103832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to support sdk version 16+, to do this, just set minSdkVersion to 16 and use compileSdkVersion as latest, i.e. 23

By doing this, if you use new features introduced in version 17+, error/warning would be displayed upon compile or when you edit your code in Android Studio.

**Edit: some more details**

One of the reason why you should do this, because you can have something like this in your code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Actually this is also how the support library work.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Answer (score 1):

You should update your **Android SDK Platform** to latest **Android 6.0 API 23.**

I got the same problem because I just updated the Support Library from SDK Manager and didn't update the SDK Platform.

[image: Check this out]
<sub>(source: [techentice.com](http://img.techentice.com/img/Android-adk-android-6.jpg))</sub>

**Or** `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'` instead of downloading the SDK Platform

Answer (score 1):

> However, this line in my build.gradle seems to lead to compilation errors after changing these:
>   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

It happens because the support libraries v23 require the API23 to compile the project.

In your `build.gradle` change the `compileSdkVersion` to **23**.

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
```

> When I comment it out, compilation will be successful. Do I not need this line? I thought it was necessary for ActionBar, etc.

Using a minsdk=16 I suggest you using the appcompat library. Widget like Toolbar, and all the [design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) (CollapsingToolbar, Snackbar...) require the appCompat.

Also if you want to backport the material design in api16, you need it.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to compile with latest version than update & install your SDK to latest which is at this time API 23.

If you really want to compile & provide support of your app on API 16 & want not to add support of later version (which does not make sense for me may be for you its good) then according to your statement

> I set compileSdkVersion and minSdkVersion to 16, because I want to
>   make sure that I don't use any features in later versions of Android

then set compileSdkVersion to 16, minSdkVersion to 16, targetSdkVersion to 16

& dependencies as compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v6:16.0.0'

check your API 16 section in SDK. it should be install

[image]

And you build.gradle should be like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "16.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.inzi.mapofcontacts"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v6:16.0.0'
}
```

According to your question it may help you.