# Gradle error, not sure what happening

Tags: android-studio

Updated Error log, i have no idea what went wrong, i updated the SDK but still no result.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
```

Xml file was untouched, i just edited the java file, but it still tells that there is something went wrong in it

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Sandeep Roy\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Hello\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":5}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}



 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.174 secs
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102553/android-studio-not-working-while-building-app-using-appcompat-v23-and-api21

Comment: add full message from above this error!