# No resource found that matches the name - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

I just downloaded Android Studio and have created a new project.

Right off the bat, I'm getting two errors:

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

and my installed packages:

[image]
[image]

What is messed up here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your gradle, compileSdkVersion is 22 while your support library version is 23. The two should match.

See [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem now. I tried below steps and worked perfectly.

In .gradle change like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
}
```

You'll get error in style file change it as below

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

modify your main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

In MainActivity remove `AppCompatActivity` like

`MainActivity extends Activity`

Comment: This would remove the `appcompat` library and thus backward compatibility with devices running < Android 5.0, if you use any of the new ui features in your code.