# Issues in android Studio. can not resolve symbol R

Tags: android, sdk

I have full update SDK. Although  there is no new update available but i have error in R. i changed the compile SDK version in project structure. then it shows error in 
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Comment: Can u show build.gradle of ur project... The problem is in library

Comment: Please add your build.gradle file and let others know what exactly you have changed

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mabdullah.listviewexample"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

> Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.
>
> Since you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.
>
> Alternatively you can continue compiling against version 22 of the Android SDK by switching to the latest support library v22.

Check the version of the support library. I had the same problem reciently and it worked well for me.