# Android: Error in the V23/Values-V23.xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm receiving error in the automatically generated XML file 
`v23/values-v23.xml`. The error is on the following items:

- `android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse`
- `android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored`

The error message is following (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LtA5.png) for more details):

> Cannot Resolve Symbol

And the error appears even when I start a new project on Android Studio. Is there anyway of fixing this?

I'm using:

- Build-Tools - 23.0.1
- API 17 - 4.2.2

Comment: are you compiling against API 17  ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/32075498/4146722

Comment: Can you please add the build.gradle file of your module to question.