# When i add appcompat-v7 library to my android project R.java is removed

Tags: android, android-appcompat

When I have added a library appcompat-v7 to my app R.java is removed and the console give the following error:

> **[2015-11-02 16:50:32 - MP] /home/users/aman.gupta/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v23/styles_base.xml:20:
>    error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.**
>
> **[2015-11-02 16:50:32 - MP] /home/users/aman.gupta/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v23/styles_base_text.xml:19:
>    error: Error retrieving parent for item:
>    No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.**

Actually I was using **android:Theme.Light** (default theme of android) and i want to use **AppCompat theme** instead of android default theme.
And In java file i want to extends **AppCompatActivity** instead of **Activity**
to give some materialistic look to my app action bar.

But the problem is that when i import appcompat-v7 library to my project, R.java was removed. So i can't do any thing.

**Note:** When i create new project then it do not give any error message and work correctly when importing appcompat-v7 library.

And i want some suggestion on how to change my current theme, So please give some suggestion from where should i start this work.

My project configuration:

```
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"
```

And i have tried to cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't target SDK 23?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name). Your SDK version must match the supported library

Comment: @Egor no, I just forgot.

Comment: Thanks @Shubham, your comment is worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Do the changes as below.

**Gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

**Style.xml**

```
    <!--.......................................MyTheme......................................-->
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <!-- Optionals..-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red_primary_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red_primary_color_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/red_placeholder_color</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MaterialEditText</item>
    </style>
    <!--........................................................................................-->
```

After clean and build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly this issue was come in Eclipse. Now most of the persons are using the Android Studio. So just the remove the **build folders** or **Clean** your project. It will work fine.