# Android Studio "Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found"

Tags: android

How could I resolve the following error in Android Studio?

> Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
> >       C:\Users\Ozzy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe
> >     package -f --no-crunch -I
> >     C:\Users\Ozzy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar
> >     -M C:\Users\Ozzy\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
> >     -S C:\Users\Ozzy\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\res\debug
> >     -A C:\Users\Ozzy\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug
> >     -m -J C:\Users\Ozzy\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\generated\source\r\debug
> >     -F C:\Users\Ozzy\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_
> >     --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.ozzy.test -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Ozzy\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
> >     Error Code:   1 Output:
> >       C:\Users\Ozzy\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v23\values.xml:5:
> >     error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
> >     matches the given name
> >     'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
> >       C:\Users\Ozzy\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v23\values.xml:20:
> >     error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
> >     matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, theres an error in your values.xml, but it could be on another xml file.

Check all your xml files.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

**You need to set compileSdkVersion to 23**.

Open **`build.gradle`** and set this

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
```

Then Clean And Rebuild (Do  Gradle Sync First)And Restart .

> [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Answer (score 0):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.

Since you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
}
```