# error at the begining of project

Tags: android, eclipse

when I put minimum sdk API 8 and TARGET SDK API 15 or 20 (in eclipse) , this errors hapen
[image]

but when I PUT Minimum sdk, API 15 OR 20 this error gone

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be happen because some of the library methods which you are using may be available only on api level 15 or upper.... check the logcat material theme you are using that is not available in that api level
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name) question it will help you