# Appcompat error. I already change the API 21 for google maps. But still have some error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-appcompat

This is mine logcat.What is the problem

```
D:\Android\SCBG\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

This is my build.gradle .Can someone tell me what is the problem with the appcompat.I Just the beginner . Help please . Is that any problem with compilesdkversion or other problem?

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.





buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}




apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kianyang.scbg"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya post already. Can u tell me what is the error??

Comment: post app `build.gradle` . In where you set `compileSdkVersion`

Comment: where is your compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya oh sorry. please check again.  i just post it.

Comment: @AmarbirSingh can you please check again.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your logcat returns

```
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

At first you need to upgrade your `compileSdkVersion` & `buildToolsVersion`.

> The buildToolsVersion property specifies what version of the build
>    tools to use .
>
> The compileSdkVersion property specifies the compilation target.
>
> targetSdkVersion — Specifies the API Level on which the application is
>   designed to run. In some cases, this allows the application to use
>   manifest elements or behaviors defined in the target API Level, rather
>   than being restricted to using only those defined for the minimum API
>   Level.

You should use

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "kianyang.scbg"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

You should call

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync Your App`** .Hope this helps .

Comment: ok. i change le. but it show me last error.   Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Comment: Is that i need to download API 23?

Answer (score 0):

Check This:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "kianyang.scbg"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Sync your gradle after adding this.