# Material Design build.gradle error

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, build.gradle, android-appcompat

I have a problem in my `build.gradle` file, the `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` doesn't match.

**Here is my `build.gradle`:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.emergencyapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    }
```

**And here is my error:**

[image]

I think it is the `buildToolsVersion` and the dependencies are causing the problem.

Comment: You need to set  `targetSdkVersion 23` instead of 22

Comment: @vovaxo It is not correct. You need to compile with 23, but you can still use the target 22.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

**You have a dependency with the support libraries v.23**, also if you are declaring v22.
It means that you have to compile with api 23.

Just use:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

Otherwise use an older version of the `com.google.android.gms:play-services`

Answer (score 0):

**I was having the same problem, What I did is**

1. First be sure that you have API level 23 (marshmallow/ android 6) installed.
2. Set `compileSdkVersion` to 23 and dependencies libraries also to greater than 23.
3. Clean and build the project.

Comment: It is not correct. You need to compile with 23, but you can still use the target 22.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I am sorry. I was just telling what i have done earlier, But didn't notice that. It can be used. I've edited my answer, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**[Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)**

> Since you are using version **23** of the `SupportLibrary`, you need
>   to compile against version `23` of the `Android SDK`.

Just change your compile sdk to `23`, already has an answer from **Google**:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183149

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

Answer (score -1):

please set targetSdkVersion 23 and dependencies

Comment: It is not correct. You need to compile with 23, but you can still use the target 22.

Comment: Thanks! this work after that I just rebuild my project then rewrite the R content in my activity class, thanks again!