# Android build failed - No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a new project in Android Studio and I'm trying to create my first activity which is supposed to allows users to login with facebook to my app. When I created the project, I got some errors (the ending part shown below)

```
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
D:\Loomius_Android\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\srinivas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.636 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

And this was at the end in the Gradle Console

```
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse\u0027.","sourcePath":"D:\\Loomius_Android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\23.1.1\\res\\values-v23\\values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":1},"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored\u0027.","sourcePath":"D:\\Loomius_Android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\23.1.1\\res\\values-v23\\values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":1},"original":""}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\srinivas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.636 secs
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Comment: Please learn to identify the correct line of error in your build logs and stacktraces, it makes debugging quite easy