# No resource found that matches... using play services 8.4.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have this is in my `build.gradle`:

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.company"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
...
}
```

and `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` and I get this error:

> Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. 
>   Error:(18)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

If I remove the dependency of play-services, everything works.

How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name

Answer (score 1):

Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 23, or switch to an older version of `play-services`.

Answer (score 1):

The `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` has a dependency with the support **library v23**.

This means that you have to compile with **api 23**.

```
android {

   compileSdkVersion 23

}
```