# Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'

Tags: android, gradle

first i was getting error to update gradle to 2.10 , I downloaded the zip extracted it and pasted it in the path , but now I am getting this error no resource found that matches given name
first i was getting error to update gradle to 2.10 , I downloaded the zip extracted it and pasted it in the path , but now I am getting this error no resource found that matches given name

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'android-apt'
    def AAVersion = '3.3.1'

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
            mavenCentral()

        }
        dependencies {
            // replace with the current version of the android-apt plugin
            classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'





        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()

    }
    dependencies {
        apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
        compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-android-support:2.5.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
        compile files('libs/CleverTapAndroidSDK-v2.0.5-20160109.jar')
        compile files('libs/google-play-services_lib.jar')
    }

    apt {
        arguments {
            androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
            // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

            // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
            // logLevel 'INFO'
            // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.vedicrishiastro.kundli"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 5
            versionName "0.1.1"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    /*apt {
        arguments {
            //androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
            // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

            // If you're using flavors you should use the following line instead of hard-coded packageName
             resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId

            // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
            // logLevel 'INFO'
            // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
        }
    }*/

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:2.0.5'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4'

        compile project(':multilevelexpindlistview')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
        apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
        compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
        compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
        compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile project(':library')
        compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.5@aar'
        compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
        compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
        compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'


    }
    android {
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
    }


    apply plugin: 'android-apt'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: Are you getting this error compiling with api 23?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set ***compileSdkVersion to 23***.

**Call**

1. `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`
2. Upgrade `buildToolsVersion`    and `compileSdkVersion` version .

   ```
   android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion '23.0.1' 


   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion // Set yours
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode // Set yours
       versionName "0.1.1" // Set yours

   }
   ```

You can visit **[Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)**

Comment: @Amiya wait i am syncking my gradle

Comment: @bipin okay. as your wish

Comment: @Amiya i changed compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion  as you said

Comment: @bipin then same problem ?

Comment: @Amiya gradle is still running lol! i'll give you feedback, you are the one who helped me few days back too right ?

Comment: @Amiya yes that was me

Comment: @bipin indeed .Let me feedback  for this problem .Hope this answer fixes .

Comment: @Amiya now i am getting this error Error:(27, 5) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:textColor' with value '@color/link_text_material_light').

Comment: @bipin call `buildToolsVersion '23.1.0'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105009/discussion-between-bipin-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score -1):

try to recompile your project with

```
compileSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 22
```