# Basic issues in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Can some one please tell me the solution to this problem in android studio: 
I am new at android... Can some one tell me the solution to resolve it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVX6o.jpg)

Comment: Please see the screen shot in [enter image description here]

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having. The easier you make it for people to understand your question the more likely you will be to get an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Comment: @Zobi your issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.

Since you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.

Alternatively you can continue compiling against version 22 of the Android SDK by switching to the latest support library v22.

Answer From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32075678/2319627