# How to change android compile skd version?

Tags: android

I created a android project on Android studio. The compile Sdk version is "API 23: Android 6.0" and I changed it to be compatible with Android 4.3. After doing this, I got some errors like below. I didn't make any other changes and I wander how to fix this issue?

```
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
```

Comment: are you using material design?

Comment: You shouldnt change the compileSdk version, but the minSdk version

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "3: Android 6.0"... Isn't that 23? Anyways, you fix that particular error by not referencing any API 23 code anywhere in your project, or go back to compiling with SDK 23, which will run absolutely fine in a 4.3 device if it is above the minimum sdk set in the Gradle file

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated the message. You are right it should be 23. Do you mean if I am using 23 Android 6.0 Sdk, my app is still working fine on android 4.3 system?

Comment: Yes, it will work on 4.3. Did you try?

Comment: Yes I tried it  works. But I want to know which version is used for target os version. Let's say if I want to specify a minimum target version, whether I should configure the minSdk?