# error retrieving parent for item

Tags: android, sdk

I have a small problem.I just need to change my compile android version from 23 to 22.Everything was fine when i was working with compilesdkversion 23.Once I switched to 22 it generate following error.

> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. Error:(2)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

I need to fix this.Please help.

Comment: have you added support design as dependencies in gradle file

Comment: no idea on support design.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-%20item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

The support library has to match the target sdk version

Regards,
Vladimir