# How to check if plugin and android SDK are the same version?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I have made an Android app via the Cordova CLI. These are the steps I have taken :

- cordova create myApp com.myCompany.myApp myApp
- cd myApp
- cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save
- cordova platform add android --save
- cordova requirements android
- cordova build android --verbose
- cordova run android

Thanks to : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova

This runs fine. So now I try and add this plugin : https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova

So I do :

- cordova plugin add cordova-admob

This doesn't work as it comes back with this error :

> Warning, could not copy necessary files for angular browser platfrom.
>   Please ensure 'www/lib/angular-admob.js' exists ...

So I created an empty file named `lib` in my `www` folder. Remove the plugin :

- cordova plugin remove cordova-admob

Then re-add :

- cordova plugin add cordova-admob

This seemed to work. So now I build and get this error :

[image: Cordova output from build]

Now I have searched for the problem and come across this : [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

The answer is as follows :

> Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major
>   version.
>
> Since you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to
>   compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.
>
> Alternatively you can continue compiling against version 22 of the
>   Android SDK by switching to the latest support library v22.

I'm not sure how to do this with the Cordova files I have, so my question is, how do I make sure that both the plugin and the android sdk are on the same versions ? If this even is my problem.

Comment: have you tried using official admob plugin by google ? [https://github.com/admob-google/admob-cordova](https://github.com/admob-google/admob-cordova)

Comment: @ArpitVasani ill give it a go, haven't come across an official google admob plugin