# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'

Tags: android

I can't fix the error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6iHQ.png)

I changed compileSdkVersion value to 21 and buildToolsVersion to 21.0.1

resolved [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile with API 23 to use a version 23 Support Library.