# Upgrade Android Studio to 2.1.2 and now getting build errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

My project built fine before, but now when upgrading to Android Studio 2.1.2 I get an error:

[image]

Here is what I have in my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.puc.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/FLurry_3.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2.jar')
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // You must install or update the Google Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.13.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
}
```

**I realize there are some issues here with build tool versions, but honestly I am not sure how to fix it. Any clues?**

**UPDATE:**

After updating the `buildToolsVersion` as mentioned below, I get the errors:

[image]

Comment: have you tried building with the latest build tools (24.0.0)?

Comment: @LordRaydenMK Would I just change the `buildToolsVersion` to 24?

Comment: `buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'` also make sure the build tools are installed in the SDK manager

Comment: Did you tried "invalide caches / restart" option? Sometimes it can resolves some problems. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html

Answer (score 0):

It happens because Build Tools revision 19.1.0 doesn't exist.

The latest version is `23.0.3.`

These tools is included in the SDK package and installed in the `<sdk>/build-tools/` directory.

Change in your `build.gradle`

```
android {
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
   // ...

}
```

[SDK Build Tools Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html)

Comment: That is giving me lots of `No resource found that matches given name` errors. Also, `Error retrieving parent for item`. Will update question with screenshot.

Comment: Have you synced gradle after did changes in buildtool version ?

Comment: open SDK manager goto Appearance & Behaviour > System Settins > Android Sdk and select Sdk Tools tab

There make sure you have installed API level 23 

Then chanage `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`

Comment: @NicHubbard see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name this will help you

Comment: Nothing seems to work. Just getting the same errors no matter what I do...

Comment: mm this happens in android studio after update android studio set default api version 23. Set `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"`

Comment: Still same errors `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/nnhubbard/AndroidstudioProjects/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`. Frustrating.

Comment: At first you go to `Build -> Clean Project`  and then go to `Build -> Rebuild Project`  and finish the error is a way