# Can't integrate android bottom bar when api level is less than 23

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to implement bottom bar in my app . I have tried several libraries like

- https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar
- https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation
- https://github.com/sephiroth74/Material-BottomNavigation

But the problem is I can't integrate any of those library when complied sdk version is less than 23 . If I try to integrate it , it says

> /home/user/droid-work/TestBBar/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v23/values-v23.xml
>
> Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testbbar"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'

    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.3.3' 
    
   //or compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1'

   //or compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.bottomnavigation:bottom-navigation:1.0.7'

}
```

Comment: Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version. Since you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.

Alternatively you can continue compiling against version 22 of the Android SDK by switching to the latest support library v22.

Courtsy:[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Answer (score 1):

Correct. If you compile less than 23, then it doesn't know what v-23 is. There is no reason why not to compile with 23 or even 24, it is the `targetSDKVersion` that makes a difference, and you can leave it at 22
Also, make sure you add the MaterialCompat library to your app.