# "Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I have a problem with `Gradle` !!

It keeps showing me errors , can some one help me to resolve this problem

**Note:** It's my first time to install android studio

[image: one]

Comment: try using this `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.0'`

Comment: Use latest support library and compile against latest sdk. [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Comment: check https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183149

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'`

Use latest support library and change your target and compile sdk also

compileSdkVersion 24

buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

targetSdkVersion 24

Answer (score 0):

Try it

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"

and you can change targetSdkVersion 23

Answer (score 0):

Please use my project gradle values and also update sdk libraries:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.student"  //change as your package name
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'



    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'


}
```

Comment: through sdk manager, Or you simply run your new empty project it'll show error and link to update the required libraries for you projects.

Comment: what can i put in this line please :

Comment: applicationId "com.example.student"  //change as your package name

Comment: your new project package name

Comment: it'll definitely, work for you, let me know when problem is solved.

Comment: problem resolved it's showing me : Build successful 
thank's

Comment: this is what i did from an anwer

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23 buildToolsVersion '23.0.0' targetSdkVersion 23

Add Following dependencies: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Try to match all versions:

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
targetSdkVersion 23

Add Following dependencies:
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

Make sure you use latest version of Sdk:
[how to update sdk](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html)

Comment: i have used your answer and it's working and know what to say

Comment: @finux see this is how You accept an answer on stackoverflow do this..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'`

which gives you all possibilities of Android 4.4.2 Kitkat API 19 and older.

In your project you're trying to use Material Themes which belongs to newer version, I mean `com.android.support:appcompat:$version`, where version > 21.

Material Design was introduced with Android 5.1 Lollipop API 21

I higly reccomend you to change your `build.gradle` file to:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1"
}
```

but of course changing `appcompat` library to version :

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
```

would be enough ;-)

Hope it would help