# Android studio doesnt find resource at givern location values-v24.xml

Tags: android

Hello below is my gradle file.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aaaaaa.aaaaaa.aaaaaa"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0.9"
        generatedDensities = []
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }

     dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

that gradle file is working fine 2 days before but from today's it gives error.I didn't make any changes but automatically it gives following error

```
E:\Studio_Workspace\aaaaa\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
```

I don't know how to solve that problem.I deleted gradle .gradle and build folder,cleaned project invalidate and restart project but error is not solved

Comment: possibility for duplicate question check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365401/how-to-fix-eror-app-build-intermediates-res-merged-debug-values-v24-values-v24-x

Comment: @vivek mahajan  i checked the given link.but my compile sdk version and support library version is also same