# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have ionic project I am getting

```
/home/manish/Softwares/cordova/maApp/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3 : AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/home/manish/Softwares/cordova/maApp/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4 : AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.


FAILURE:  FAILED
Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/manish/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

After upgrading to `Android SDk Tools` `25.2.5` i am getting this error.

```
ionic -v
1.7.14
```

Cordova `1.6.0`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name

Comment: In case of ionic `Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.` wher shall i make those changes?

Comment: You have `values-v24.xml` in your error, but yet you're using `build-tools/23.0.2`

Comment: I don't know what was the issue but removing `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` and adding back solved it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Answer (score 1):

In your module's app, look at `build.gradle`, in your `dependencies` block:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
```

Make sure that it matches your `compileSdkVersion` in `android` block:

```
    compileSdkVersion 25
```

Look at:
[Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Comment: compileSdk 24 should fix the error mentioned, not the targetSdk

Comment: True @cricket_007. Updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading your gradle file in compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion and com.android.support:appcompat-v7 version numbers may solve your problem

I upgraded them to 26+ and solved the problem

```
compileSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 26
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```