# ionic 2 - build android failed when add cordova.plugins.diagnostic plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic2

I try to create ionic 2 app with below steps:

1- `npm install -g cordova`

2- `npm install -g ionic`

3- `npm install -g typescript`

4- `ionic start sampleApp tutorial --v2`

for serve and see in browser use this command :

```
ionic serve
```

for build android apk file download jdk 8 and android sdk manager and install all api and set ANDROID-HOME and after use this command :

```
ionic platform add android

ionic build android
```

every things is ok and work very well but I want give GPS state and for this reason add `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` with this command :

```
ionic plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic

npm install --save @ionic-native/diagnostic
```

but after add diagnostic plugin and run `ionic build android` console give me error and build failed .I search in google and find this page :

[Ionic android build fails, no matches found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681030/ionic-android-build-fails-no-matches-found)

and this pages :

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/build-failed-android/38071/6

but I don't know how to solve this problem

my project and system info:

```
ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed

<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

Comment: does `ionic serve` work after adding plugin?

Comment: yes work in browser but give me cordova not available
error in console that this error for "ionic serve disables all the cordova plugins, because it is not running on a device"

Comment: ok..any error logs on build failed?

Comment: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: are you using ionic 2 or 3? more precisely ionic-native version...

Comment: I install ionic with npm install -g ionic and my info is => ionic -v : 2.2.1  and ionic-native : 2.9.0

Comment: you can compare your package.json with the [starter app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json) if you want..the docs generally are updated with that

Comment: in my package.json  ionic-native/core is 3.4.2 but when use this command "npm info ionic-native version" in console give me 2.9.0

Comment: can you show your package.json? maybe you have both entries?/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141889/discussion-between-roox-and-suraj).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Android target sdk version matches the android sdk build tools in your android SDK manager , for your case check that you have android sdk build tools version 23 in sdk manager
i tried to recreate the problem and app runs on device well on my side, my ionic 
ionic info is

```
cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v7.8.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Also, upgrade your node version, current version as of this writing is 7.9.0

```
ionic plugin rm cordova.plugins.diagnostic
cordova platform remove android
```

then 
    ionic plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
    cordova platform add android

then
    ionic build android