# After installation: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

After installation

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

[image]

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32075678/7604342

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle console points at `build-tools/21.1.2` and your image shows you opened an API `25.3.0` resource file.

The Material resources are only in API 23+, and/or in the `appcompat:design` library that you need to compile in your `build.gradle` file

You'll also want to update the `buildTools` and `compileSdk`

---

And you are using Android Studio `1.1.0`, so I don't understand "*After installation*" since that is not the latest version.