# ionic run android failing with: values-v24/values-v24.xml:4 No resource found 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, android-gradle-plugin

Uptil yesterday everything was working fine.
Now all of a sudden I am getting this error (mentioned in title).

minSdkVersion is set to 16
TargetSdk is set to 25

All answers for previous such queries have not helped.
Is there some upstream issue.

My team and I are all hitting the same issue. No code was updated in our app. We just ran the build and hit this error.

Comment: You have to compile with api 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This arises from a mismatch between the Android compile SDK version and the support library / build tools version ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)).

Even if you changed no code in the project, if the Android SDK modules were updated or the `cordova-android` platform version changed, this would cause the observed error.

You can resolve it by updating the project to use the most recent `cordova-android` version:

```
cordova platform rm android 
  && cordova platform add android@latest --save 
  && cordova build android
```

Also make sure the Android SDK components (Support Library, build tools, platform tools) are up-to-date.