# Can't able to Resolve Firebase after Installing google playservice and google repository in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, sdk, google-play-services

As i change my Windows OS from 8.1 to 10..After Installing windows 10,I start Installed Android Studio 1.5.1.After Installing Android Studio,I have downloaded SDK...After this the Android Studio Opens well..Then i started doing my project..I have created new project..And i am in need of including **Firebase** to my project..So i have Included respective dependencies for that..

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.projects.ajayjayendran.sample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.3'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.9'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(Project:Sample)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am getting this following Error..I know that this Question is already in Stack Overflow but it does not resolve my problem..I have lost one day..

[image]

In old Questions,they gave solution as Installing **Google Repository** and **Google play Service** in SDK Manager..Even after Installing this,I am getting this Same Error..Please anyone here Resolve my problem..

[image]

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Maybe Using version 10.2.0 would solve the problem

Comment: okay..Let me try..then what version should i use for firebase ui? @InnocentKithinji

Comment: Already i downgrade the Firebase version from 10.2.4 to 10.2.3..however i downgraded it to 10.2.0,i am getting the same error as i mentioned..

Comment: Have You checked that the gradle offline mode is not activated

Answer (score 1):

Created a new project, copied your gradle files, and managed to reproduce the errors. However, I managed to make it compile smoothly after a few changes.

1. I don't know where you got `10.2.3` versions, but I edited the Firebase dependencies back to `10.2.4` (see versions [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20170428)).
2. I'm presuming it's just a typo, but the Firebase UI library doesn't have a specified `1.1.9` version (see the versions [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)). I changed mine to `1.1.0`.

After *clean building* the project with the changes above, it started to throw a different error. One where you have to make sure that the Compile SDK version, build tools version, and the support library versions are aligned (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32075678/4625829)).

3. So from the above post, I edited out the `compileSdkVersion` to `25` and used the latest support library versions (`25.x.x`).

The resulting app gradle file (builds with no problems):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gradle.testapp2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

P.S.: It's also advisable to have your Android SDK Tools updated.