# Error retrieving parent for item : No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services

Please do not tag this question as duplicate... I did not manage to find a solution on the other posts, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)... :(

I have got the following error when I launch my app:

```
/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v23/values-v23.xml
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

Here is my Gradle at the app level:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22 
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2' 
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tasmanic.radio.fm"
        minSdkVersion 14 
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1' 
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1' 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.1'


    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

At the project level:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1' 
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}
```

Note that I want to keep targetSdkVersion equal to 22.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks !!!

Comment: If you see the log, the error is in a folder for v23 and you are targeting to v22. If you delete this folder may be it works.

Comment: have you used any values under resource folder for version 23 or higher ? Check res folder, if you found any folder or file contains v23 with its name try to remove it and build your project.

Answer (score 2):

Google Play services / Firebase 10.2.1 depends on version 24.0.0 of the Android Support Library, which you can see by running `gradlew androidDependencies`.

This means you **must** compile with API 24 or higher. That does **not** mean you have to target API 24 or higher though, as explained in [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd).

The last version of Google Play services to depend on a v22 version of the Support Library was `8.4.0`, which does not include any of the Firebase functionality (introduced in 10.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

try change Widget.Material to Theme.AppCompat in your styles-files, that match api level < 21