# Getting no resource found errors

Tags: android, react-native

In a react-native project, I'm getting the following errors during gradle build

```
/Users/josephtibbertsma/Source/SkyHi-App/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml
  Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
  Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
  Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
  Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
```

I've seen other threads about this issue such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name). The answers seem to be saying that I need to change my configuration somehow. But I shouldn't need to change my config, because this exact same config was working before. I tried updating a library and I got this error. Then I ran git reset --hard to go back to the old commit, but the error is somehow still there! I don't understand why this would happen. Also, the error is coming from react-native-fbsdk. Would I have to edit the config files for that package to fix this error?

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-navigation')
    compile project(':react-native-config')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling using sdk 24+?

Comment: I don't know. How to find out?

Comment: I assume you have a Gradle file? You had to setup the Android SDK somehow

Comment: Yeah it was auto generated by react-native. In my build.gradle it says compileSdkVersion 25, buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

Comment: Okay, and your dependencies section is also using the same versions? 25?

Comment: I will post my build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the post you linked to says, the support libraries must match your compileSdk.

Update the line that contains

```
support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
```

And you may want to also add the Support Design Library

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Also make sure that you update the **nested projects**.

Plus, if you think it worked before, and "suddenly broke", then that could be because you're always compiling the very latest version of `react-native:+` (hint : don't use just a plus as a version )

Comment: 1) it needs to match 25, right? 2) the documentation says `25.3.1` is the latest... https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: I changed to compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1" but I got the same error...

Comment: Then, try adding the design library since you're missing themes

Comment: Added compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1' to build.gradle, but same error

Comment: Hmm. It's some combination of compiling these libraries, that much I know. I do think it's strange that you have `targetSdkVersion 22` and are trying to compile code with a greater sdk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145162/discussion-between-joseph-fakelastname-and-cricket-007).

Comment: If the error still exists after a git reset, then you need to run a gradle clean

Comment: If you end up here, make sure you follow the "update the nested projects" part of this answer. That's what solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to node_modules -> react-native-fbsdk -> android -> build.gradle and change

> com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+

to

> com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1