# Manifest merger failed when adding Firebase-ui-auth in android

Tags: android

I am unable to configure `Firebase-ui-auth` in my app. I have tried all versions of `firebase-ui-auth` but have so far failed.

I read many questions related to `firebase-ui-auth` but none have helped. I do not want to change my current SDK version.

I have added the below line in `gradle.build(Project:Project_Name) :`

```
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
```

and this is my `gradle.build(Module:app)` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nishant.kitbook"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
 Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@supportsRtl value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35   is also present at [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1] AndroidManifest.xml:14:18-45 value=(false).  Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-33:19 to override.
```

Comment: Tried the suggestion given by compiler?  add
'tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"'

Comment: after adding 'tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"' in menifest, there is another error. Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32075678/5110536

Comment: my sdk version is 23 and support version is 23.4.0. what should i do then

Comment: check the support library version of the library that you are using, these should be same as yours

Comment: thanks for your help, i changed firebase-ui-auth to version 1.0.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this eat my half a day. i just changed `firebase-ui-auth` version to 1.0.1 from 1.1.1 and it worked. if anyone got any problem relating `firebase-ui` just check `firebase-ui` version one by one in descending order, one should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had to drop by a version from `2.1.0` to `2.0.1` for the Gradle file to compile properly.

Comment: what sdk version and build tool version are you using by the way ?

Comment: buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'         minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24