# Application doesn't run for this error : Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android

I downloaded a source code and just import in my android studio. Now my project is showing this error.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
/home/td/Downloads/link/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

The problem indicates on this file

```
..../link/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml
```

How can I get rid of this. I searched several things. Some of them are telling about changing minSDKversion but this won't work.

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.creativedroids.link"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
compile files('libs/tween-engine-api-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/tween-engine-api.jar')
compile files('libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-3.3.2.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major
>   version.

You can do it on the gradle file mentioned in the question below

[Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to AppCompat v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Comment: please see my updated question. I don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the newest play services then you have to compile with new sdk - at least 26.

> When you upgrade your app’s Play services dependencies to 11.2.0 or later, your app’s build.gradle must also be updated to specify a compileSdkVersion of at least 26 (Android O).

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to update your `compileSdkVersion` to 25.

In my case this is what got it to work:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
```

I'm on API 26, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

It means your `compileSdkVersion` should be to match support lib v24

change `compileSdkVersion` to 24