# Android Studio Project corrupted?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I started Android Studio I got a bunch of error messages saying a bunch of plugins were missing or uninstalled or whatever. I restarted Android Studio a couple of times and it seemed as though that problem fixed itself. (No idea what was going on there.)

Then a new problem arised. The project I have been working on seems to be damaged/corrupt. I don't know how or why. Here's what it says:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>   C:\Users\Peter\AndroidStudioProjects\AlarmClock\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
>   Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>   Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>   Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>   C:\Users\Peter\AndroidStudioProjects\AlarmClock\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml
>   Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>   Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>   Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1.255 secs

I booted up another project and it worked just fine.

The last thing I did with the corrupt project was change something (not sure why) and as a result it would crash every time I clicked a certain button while running the project. I was about to start debugging it today, when this whole mess happened.

In MainActivity it says:

> Cannot Resolve Symbol 'R'

I imagine that's a bad thing..

EDIT:
I got it working, but I still have an issue. See the screenshots below:

[image: My faulty project]

Above is what the project tree looks like now.

[image: correct project]

Above is another project tree from a project which is working correctly. I want both to look like this. (The faulty project used to look like this.)

Comment: I once had similar issue. I deleted the intermediate folder and restarted android studio is worked fine for me.

Comment: did you try invalidating cache and restarting android studio?

Comment: I actually found a solution by accident only a few minutes after posting. What I did was: Click 'File -> Project Structure' then change the Compile Sdk Version. I had changed it to API 21 earlier without knowing what I was doing. Now I changed it back to API 25, and suddenly it started working.
Still have no idea how or why, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot Resolve Symbol 'R' is a common error and most often, the cause is a malformed XML file.

Check your layouts, menus etc for anything that should not be there. It could be as simple as you accidentally typing a random character into one of the files or an invalid String.

Once the build completes normally, the other errors usually go away.

Many more options are listed in this question.

["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

Edit:

Choose Android View from the menu indicated.

[image: Project View]

Comment: The original problem was solved, but a new problem arised. I edited my original post and added screenshots. Could you take a look at it, please?

Answer (score 0):

> I imagine that's a bad thing..

Not necessarily, don't worry.

You can try to:

1. Rrebuild your project in Android studio.
2. From command line run `gradlew clean assembleDebug` and check output.
3. Verify you are using compatible versions, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name).

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project doing this

> Build > Clean Project or Build > Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions.

1. Check resources and xml files.
2. In android studio File-> Invalidate Caches / Restart
3. Clean project.
4. Delete .gradle from C:\%USERPROFILE%.gradle.
5. Delete .gradle .idea and build files from your project.