# react-native run-android compile fails: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'

Tags: android, react-native

When running `react-native run-android` it throws me the following error:

> /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3:
>   AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4:
>   AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
>
> /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

I thought this error was related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name) question about the build version SDK, but I have tried everything with no success.

I have been going on for about 6 hours and really need some help.

build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lisdo"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
...
}

dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-google-places')
compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
compile project(':react-native-video')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Comment: You ever get an answer to this? I am running into the same issue right now

Comment: me too after upgrading some dependencies ( react, react-native and more ) , have to found which one make this

Answer (score 0):

Check [this comment](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/499#issuecomment-396545716) on create-react-native package, it seems like some modules uses a version of native modules that's not the version you use in the native side of your app, so, from the library, it can't fetch the assets.

Add this line at the end of your `android/build.gradle` file, under your RN directory.

```
subprojects { 
     afterEvaluate { 
         project -> if (project.hasProperty("android")) { 
             android { 
                 compileSdkVersion 26 
                buildToolsVersion '26.0.2' 
             } 
         } 
     } 
 }
```

It just forces the version to the one you set.

> It' `android/build.gradle` not `android/app/build.gradle`.