# Android: problems with play-services-ads

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

I'm trying to import an old Eclipse project into Android Studio, in order to show ads.

Here are the dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
}
```

But when I try to build the project, the Java compiler gives the following errors:

> TextAppearance.Material.Notification not found.
>
> TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Info not found.
>
> TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Time not found.
>
> TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title not found.

Thanks in advance for suggestions!

Comment: Latest version of support library is 27. I can't even think how old could be v19...

Comment: Yes. I tried to import a newer version but the problems are similar: it can't find TextAppearance.Material, Body1, Body2, Button, Caption, etc.

Comment: Try to compare the version of the support library against the version of Android SDK. It should be matched. See also this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I solved changing compileSdkVersion from 19 to 26. I also changed targetSdkVersion.