# Gradle build error."minsdkversion 14 cannot be different than version l declared in library"?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-appcompat

Hi everyone I am new to android developing.I download the latest version of android studio 1.3.2  yesterday.But when I start a new project for testing, gradle give me an error.
My gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.niyamat.testing3"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

      dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'

}
```

The error is

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be different than version L declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0-rc1]   C:\Users\Niyamat\Documents\Testing3\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.0-rc1\AndroidManifest.xml
```

I know there are some question about the same error but I didn't find any good solution.
So please someone help me?

Comment: remove the <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" /> attribute from AndroidManifest.xml ,if you have declared there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your issue.

> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be different than version L declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0-rc1]

It is quite strange that you have in your sdk folder the **preview version** of appcompat 21.
This version was published with the lollipop preview (**api-L**) and had the `minSdk = L`. It is the reason of your issue (because you have `minSdkVersion 15`)

You should not have this folder in your sdk. Check with the **SDK Manager** if it is updated.

Then you can modify your `build.gradle` removing the +.

**Support libraries v21**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

**Support libraries v22** (require compileSdkVersion 22)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

**Support libraries v23** (require compileSdkVersion 23)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriele Mariotti.I first don't understand your answer but after a few time later I understand that compile sdkversion should match the support library version.Then I do it and my gradle sync successfully.

Answer (score 1):

### Whats your Logcat Throws

```
 Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be different than version L declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0-rc1]
```

**What should you Do**

1. Remove `minSdkVersion` version from **Manifest** .You already declare it in your **build.gradle** .
2. Use this `compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'` instead yours.
3. Compile `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1'`

First of all remove this line from your **Manifest** .

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

**Finally**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.niyamat.testing3"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

      dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1'

}
```

Comment: Hi IntelliJ Amiya I tried your solution But when I sync the grdle,gradle gave me an error    Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: when press  Install Repository and sync project their is a error .Photos of error https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bze-_k4O9A53dnFLWlVrY1g4RDQ

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284236/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v722-and-com-android-supportre

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a previous version of the app compat into your lib folder specific for android L.

Also you should set the version for `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` and the `appcompat-v7` to be the same.

In your case, the `buildToolVersion` should be "21.1.2".

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is the reason why android studio complains / suggests **NOT** using `.+` in your compiles.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
```

It forces compile with absolute last version of appcompat 21 which is `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0-rc1` (as you can see from error you got). That version does not allow `minSdkVersion 15` - it's made for Lollipop. Change your compile appcompat to version number that does allow minSdkVersion 15 to solve the issue.