# Android Studio : Unable to use Map Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-studio

when i create map google map activity in android studio... after creation it takes time for syncing gradle... then it show following error....

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            hhttps://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            hhttps://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>        Required by:
>            MrCabv1:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            hhttps://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            hhttps://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/MABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>        Required by:
>            MrCabv1:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
>   Could not find com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.pom
>           https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.aar
>        Required by:
>            MrCabv1:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0

Comment: Paste your build.gradle for the application please

Comment: build.gradle(Project:ABC)
`/ Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
`

Comment: Paste as an edit in your post; easier to read. Also paste the build.gradle for the overall application and not for specific modules

Comment: build.gradle (Module:App)
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {  compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig { applicationId "myapp" minSdkVersion 16 targetSdkVersion 21 versionCode 1 versionName "1.0 }
    buildTypes {
        release { minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'} }}
dependencies {compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'}
`

Comment: these were two gradle files in my app

Comment: Your module build.gradle file is missing a few of the dependencies mentioned in your error log such as 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'. Add these in the dependencies section.

Comment: how can i add ?? this is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it means you does not assign any or wrong dependencies for

```
com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0
```

and

```
com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
```

Solution. Go to Gradle Script -> build.gradle(Module:app) -> dependencies and add the correct version to build.gradle according to the API needs(Your SDK API).
Make sure it is correct i.e compileSDKVersion 23 and buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" so you need

```
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.1.1'
```

Refer  [failed to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22 and com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284236/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v722-and-com-android-supportre)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouter.html

Comment: shall i add this same as it is ?
{compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.1.1'

Comment: It's depends on your compileSDKVersion and buildToolsVersion above.. If you are rocking API 23, then you should.. For more information, http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: Have you change the compileSDKVersion and buildToolsVersion to the lastest update?