# Android / Gradle build failed: Could not find dependency

Tags: java, android

I don't know what to do; I'm stuck. I have the following dependencies, and everything was working fine before:

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.1'
        compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
        compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
        compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    }
```

Then, suddenly, it started saying:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         hamro-doctor-android:app:unspecified
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         hamro-doctor-android:app:unspecified
         hamro-doctor-android:app:unspecified > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0
         hamro-doctor-android:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0
         hamro-doctor-android:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:22.2.0
         hamro-doctor-android:app:unspecified > com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         hamro-doctor-android:app:unspecified > com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         hamro-doctor-android:app:unspecified > com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.0.2
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         hamro-doctor-android:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         hamro-doctor-android:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom
         file:/home/yubraj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         hamro-doctor-android:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
```

I'm not sure what changed or what caused this to start happening.

Comment: You have included the dependencies but Gradle is not able to find those dependencies to download them.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/29284236/18157

Comment: Thanks jim garrison, i think google play services may required the v23.2.0 , i updated my SDK and its now working. thanks buddy for this.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error, i then opened my android sdk manager and noticed some updates were pending. All good now after updates, i did need to restart my "mac".

Comment: Yea u r right, i noticed later the libraries i am using are using the latest sdk which i hadnot installed, so after installation everything went fine.