# Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-gradle-plugin

While adding dependency implementation 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.4' to my project, Android Studio throws exception Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7. Then I tried adding dependency for recyclerview. Still getting same error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.someapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.commonsware.cwac:saferoom:0.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: can you post the log cat error message

Comment: I get only this Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7 in gradle log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Upgrading all the support dependencies to the latest version, solved the issue. You can check the latest version of dependencies [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html). I upgraded the support dependencies to the latest version **28.0.0-alpha3**. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 42):

I have same problem and i'm change order of `repositories` in biuld.gradle (app) and problem solved.

Change :

```
 jcenter()
 google()
```

To :

```
 google()
 jcenter()
```

Hope it's help

Comment: you saved my life. How on earth you figured this out I will never know

Comment: I'm happy to helped you,but keep in mind that google have so much stupid bugs and solution are more stupid! try something weird to solve your weird problem

Comment: WoW! This helps

Comment: I casually do android programming . Took me 1 month to solve this problem. All Hail Radesh !

Answer (score 2):

1. In Android Studio go to build.gradle (Project: YourProjectName), NOT the build.gradle (Module: app)
2. Change the code, so it looks like this (switch google() and jcenter()):

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Add maven to repositories and it should work

Comment: Already maven is added in project gradle 
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
        }


    }

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why. But my exact same problem has been solved with commenting all of android support dependencies.
It's so strange. But now my project runs without adding another version of these dependencies. When I put only one of these dependencies, I have a warning between ver 27.1.1 and 28.0.0 of support libraries. But I've only used version 28 on this project. It means there is all of these dependencies somewhere in the gradle which obviously is not written by me, or may be it's in the sth like cache (So strange bug).

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

If any of the above solutions did not work try to remove Maven repository and resync again.
this line in build.gradle

```
    maven {
    url "https://storage.googleapis.com/snap-kit-build/maven"
    }
```

That's work for me in some projects.
Or replace this line

```
    'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.....'
```

With this line

```
    'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot resolve because the version you are adding might not be in the Maven repository. Check your Api level and choose the appropriate version.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284236/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v722-and-com-android-supportre) might be of help.

Comment: Studio throws this error while I try to add carousellayoutmanager:carousel dependency in app gradle. And more over my api level is 27 and I was adding recyclerview dependency of version 27.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error `Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7`. Even though project worked before and I just moved it to another machine without changes in gradle files.

Full clear of gradle service folder helped me. By default it is located in `C:\Users\username\.gradle`
I closed Android Studio and deleted that folder. After that gradle made clean sync and it ended with success.

Maybe deleting of only cached libraries in `C:\Users\username\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\recyclerview-v7` would help but I didn't check it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude `recyclerview-v7` module from the library you want to add:

```
compile ('YOUR_DEPENDENCY') {
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use for example this dependency: implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0' in your build.gradle(Module: app) and use 'sync project with Gradle Files' then it will get this dependency. It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

in androidx version I added implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0" to my gradle and it solved the issue