# ionic cordova play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

today I woked up to the morning when I can not run my Ionic project like I was able a few hours ago.

```
$ ionic cordova run android --device -lsdc
```

gives:

```
[cordova]  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[cordova]  
[cordova]  * What went wrong:
[cordova]  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
[cordova]  > Could not find play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1).
[cordova]    Searched in the following locations:
[cordova]        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar
[cordova]  
[cordova]  * Try:
[cordova]  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[cordova]  
[cordova]  BUILD FAILED
```

I have tried to delete Android platform, didn't help.

```
$ cordova -v
8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
```

please, suggest what should I do to run the project again.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: didn't had time yet. like, that jcenter repository was removed, someone should raise cordova fix or publish 'hot-fix' steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version is your Android Cordova platform? I just got this same error on Cordova 8.1.2, but after updating my Android platform from 7.0.0 to 7.1.1 (the latest as of this writing) I was able to build successfully.

`cordova platform list`

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform update android
cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 2):

I temporary fixed it moving jcenter() in the build.gradle file to the bottom of the parameters (see [Android gradle Failed to resolve: play-services-basement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52948514/10557307)) 
e.g. i changed this:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

to this:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()
}
```

before it was in the first line - therefore it cannot find the basement file.

Comment: yeah, that too. then your project runs?

Comment: yes - the project runs after you change the order of the repositories - just be sure that jcenter() is at the bottom.

Comment: i just found out that in cordova android version 7.1.1 release notes they say:
"(android) Move google maven repo ahead of jcenter" -> so if possible, just update your android version :)

Comment: I did, but I had another issue after that with inapppurchases, so I had to change package to this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase-fixed