# Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0 (and keep database in app)

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, mobile

I can't add Firebase database in my application and when I remove ":15.0.0" the point 2 is disable.[can't resolve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8DQ2.png)
[disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TszQM.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891617/failed-to-resolve-recyclerview-v7)

Comment: @Radesh no google() and jcenter() are in this order

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `15.0.0`. You can't have two versions listed. You should also *read* the error you get instead of just posting it. It tells you exactly what to do.

You need to implement `firebase-core`:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

Comment: ok but now the point 2 "Add the Realtime Database to your app" is disable

Comment: That's a different issue.

Comment: just do it ! its ok

Comment: Why it's disable if it's good ? Because I can't acces to my database