# "Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.0.0" when enable data binding

Tags: android

I'm working on Mycroft-Android project ( [github](https://github.com/MycroftAI/Mycroft-Android) ) and I can't enable data binding. Gradle will throw an error, says :

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.0.0

All the help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891617/failed-to-resolve-recyclerview-v7)

Answer (score 0):

you can try Upgrade Android Support Library.