# Android dependency 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7' has different version for the compile (22.1.1) and runtime (27.1.0) classpath

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Hello I have issue on android dependency it shows the recyclerview error "'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7' has different version for the compile (22.1.1) and runtime (27.1.0) classpath"

It's conflict with the common library's recyclerview.Please check the gradle file and give me some solution.

Issue

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android dependency 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7' has different version for the compile (22.1.1) and runtime (27.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.AppPreBuildTask.lambda$run$0(AppPreBuildTask.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.AppPreBuildTask.handleArtifact(AppPreBuildTask.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.AppPreBuildTask.run(AppPreBuildTask.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:780)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:747)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
```

**Project Level Gradle**

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
    ext {
        propCompileSdkVersion = 27
        propMinSdkVersion = 16
        propTargetSdkVersion = propCompileSdkVersion
        propVersionCode = 1
        propVersionName = '3.18.6'
        kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
        support_libs = '27.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App Level Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.gallery"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 169
        versionName "3.6.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "gallery")
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

ext {
    leakCanaryVersion = '1.5.4'
}

dependencies {
    //    implementation 'com.simplemobiletools:commons:3.17.23'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.exif:library:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.12'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    //implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.tibbi:subsampling-scale-image-view:v3.10.0-fork'
    debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:$leakCanaryVersion"
    releaseImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$leakCanaryVersion"
    implementation project(':commons')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.booking:rtlviewpager:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ajalt.reprint:core:3.2.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:0.2'
}

Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = new File('signing.properties')
if (propFile.canRead()) {
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    if (props != null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('PASSWORD')) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['PASSWORD']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['PASSWORD']
    } else {
        println 'signing.properties found but some entries are missing'
        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
} else {
    println 'signing.properties not found'
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**Library Gradle(common)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion propCompileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion propMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion propTargetSdkVersion
        versionCode propVersionCode
        versionName propVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_libs"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_libs"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.booking:rtlviewpager:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.andrognito.patternlockview:patternlockview:1.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.github.ajalt.reprint:core:3.2.1@aar'

    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}

apply from: '../bintray-upload.gradle'
```

Comment: did you use com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 ?

Comment: No, you can use all the dependency @SambitMallick

Comment: If API 27 then use **`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`**, 
**`implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'`** @akhilbatlawala

Comment: not working @Ali

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284236/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v722-and-com-android-supportre @akhilbatlawala

Comment: i added implementation com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 it solve but now shows dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (23.1.1) and runtime (27.1.1) @Ali

Comment: just for once replace "implementation" with "api" for first two dependencies

Comment: No can't apply `api` now days used `implementation`@SambitMallick

Comment: where this error come in `gradle(app)` or `gradle(library)` @akhilbatlawala

Comment: Now it's working thanks @Ali

Comment: Yoo Welcome @akhilbatlawala

Answer (score 0):

You must use it  `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'`

not `implementation 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:0.2'`